# How to fit a 3D matrix in keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras

I am creating a regression model with keras. I have `10` `145 * 5` matrices of ten digits. I am facing problem to fit the `10` `145 * 5` matrices in keras model.

`X` is input matrix

`In: X.shape`

`Out: (10, 145, 5)`

`y` is target matrix

`In: y.shape`

`Out: (10,)`

For each `145 * 5` matrix there will be one value in the target matrix

**Making the model**

`In: model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_dim=145),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
    Dense(output_dim=10)
])`

Although the previous line is not throwing any error or warning but I am quite sure that it is **not** the correct way to fit the model in this case.

`In: model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mse')`

No problem so far. But when I am trying to fit the matrices

`In: model.fit(X, y.reshape(-1, 1))`

After this line I am getting a long Traceback which ultimately says

`ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 145, 5)`

Please help me to correctly fit the matrices in the model. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `input_shape` instead of `input_dim`. Also since the number of dimensions of output is changing you need to use `Flatten` or `Reshape` as one of the dimensions.

```
from keras.layers import Flatten

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(145,5)),
    Flatten(),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
    Dense(output_dim=10)
])

model.summary()
```

Use `model.summary()` to check the structure of your model for better understanding.

Comment: Do I need to flatten the matrices while fitting the model?

Comment: I am getting this `ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 10) but got array with shape (10, 1)` while fitting.

Comment: No the flatten layer will automatically do it for you. You can use the input as is.

Comment: Ok that means your output_dim is 1 use `Dense(output_dim=1)` as the last layer.